# Importing a skill in power apps virtual agent

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to add a skill to PVA and getting an error message as shown below. The Skill works fine in the Azure bot service and responds well. The allow list has the PVA bot id added.

How do we resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, this was related to CORS setting in the App Service configuration. Add https://copilot.preview.yourdomain.com to cors setting.